# Angular 4: Auto Refresh Data on change in Database with PHP API

Tags: php, angular, subscribe

Fetching data from PHP API

Service:

```
readUser(usrIdData:any,api:string):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(GblFunctions.getAPIUrl(api),usrIdData,{
      headers: new HttpHeaders ({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }

createUser(userData:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(GblFunctions.getAPIUrl('creatUser'),userData);
  }
```

Component A:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.readPlayer();
  }
readPlayer(){
    this.gblService.getUsrDtls(GblFunctions.getAllData()).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.usr = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      } 
    );
  }
```

In this reading all the data in DB, but on submitting data through from in other component. data in this component is not refreshing, Please suggest the solution.

Comment: look into custom event emitter or subject so that if one of the components updates the data the other one gets a notification and refreshes its data https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/

Comment: Can you share stackblitz example?